# Generate API signaure like hash_hmac in ruby encoding

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate API signature in ruby, I have code write in PHP, I want to match with exact output.

PHP Code

```
$strToSign = "A"
$api_key = "B"
hash_hmac('sha256', $strToSign, $api_key, false) 
OutPut= 7c1264983a16877cd924d705b4e1305cc637f074ed41d081472142902bfac1c6
```

I want same output with ruby, which library or encoding should I used to match with the exact output.

I am using OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest() to match the output but it is giving me different string

For reference, I am using following code to convert it but did not work for me, Please help me in getting output.

Ruby Code

```
   str_sign = "A"
   api_key = "B"
   OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', str_sign, api_key)
   OutPut= 8189105e6b068e191c753c0e8acc2390f4fddef5bf992c524b5234b24a59d773
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer, where I made mistake.

In ruby HMAC.hexdigest() accept the reverse parameter than hash_hmac().
It required api_key first then str_sign.

EX.

```
   str_sign = "A"
   api_key = "B"
   OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', api_key, str_sign)
   OutPut= 7c1264983a16877cd924d705b4e1305cc637f074ed41d081472142902bfac1c6
```